# TorBrowser commandline set torrc

Tags: configuration

Is there any solution to run, on windows, TorBrowser (firefox.exe) from command line and set the torrc configuration files?

Or can i set the ExitNote from commandline?

Comment: I think you mean 'exitNode'

Comment: Sure i mean exitNode :)

I didn't found a solutin for this by the way but i used a workaround by using multiple configuration files and a batch to switch to the need configuration file